# Is it possible to build a family tree in python using networkx nodes and edges?

Tags: python, nodes, networkx, edges

Is it possible to build a family tree like the one below in python utilizing networkx? And if so which layout?

I want a layout lithe this one but networkx is giving me hard time?Any Ideas how to reproduce it?Thanks

[Family Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7Mr4.png)

Im trying to achieve it but newtworkx edges are not drawn correctly.I want the edge connecting from parent to child to start from the middle of the edge connecting parents instead I get this

```
import networkx as nx 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
# Create an empty directed graph 
G = nx.DiGraph()  
# Add the nodes (family members) 
G.add_nodes_from(['Father of Me', 'Mother Of Me', 'Me'])  
# Add the edges (relationships) 
G.add_edge('Father of Me', 'Me', pos=(1, 0)) 
G.add_edge('Mother Of Me', 'Me') 
G.add_edge('Father of Me', 'Mother Of Me')  
# Set the positions of the nodes for plotting 
pos = {'Father of Me': (0, 1), 'Mother Of Me': (2, 1), 'Me': (1, 0)}  
# Draw the graph with labels 
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos, with_labels=True)  
# Show the plot 
plt.show()
```

[Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRpQa.png)

Comment: "*but networkx is giving me hard time*", "*newtworkx edges are not drawn correctly*": please share code of what you've done so far. Take into account that it should be an [mcve]. Also, please do [provide your research so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1256347)

Comment: Don't try to cram your code into a comment, instead [edit] your question to include the relevant details.